# convert .avi/.flv to itunes readable format without increasing video size

Tags: itunes, format, avi, video-conversion

I have installed itunes in my PC to organize my media. I have tons of videos in .avi/flv format and i want to convert them to a format readable by itunes so i can add them to the library.

What is the best format/codecs etc to make the conversion to keep the video quality and not increase the file size?

I am using Oxelon Media converter.

Answer (score 3):

Conversion between different codecs will always reduce the video quality, no matter what. Even if the file size is encreased.

That being said, the best video codec out there that has a good tradeoff between size and video quality is MPEG-4/AVC h.264. The Oxelon Media converter however doesn't support that.

I'd strongly suggest you to try out [**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/details.php), a free video conversion utility that supports MPEG-4/AVC and even has some presets for iPhone/iPod/AppleTV that will probably fit your needs.

Comment: Both AVI and FLV are _containers_. There is a high possibility that the _codecs_ used are already supported by iTunes and all that's needed is to put them into, say, MP4: `ffmpeg -i foo.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy foo.m4v`

Comment: @grawity You are a 100% right, thanks! Although I think that iTunes is a bit picky. The benefit of your option is that no quality is lost when transcoding.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite application for ipod videos is : [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/index.html)

You can set your output settings for Ipod.

It's really easy to use & configure.